# Python: Error al usar la librería pyautogui con Thonny en Windows

Tags: python

La librería está correctamente instalada con pip.

```
import pyautogui

import time

while True:

    print (pyautogui.position())
    time.sleep(1)
```

> > > %Run 'pyautogui chivato ratón.py'
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "I:\MEGA\Programación\Python\pyautogui chivato ratón.py", line 1, in 
> > >           import pyautogui
> > >         File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\backend.py", line 317, in _custom_import
> > >           module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

Intento instalarla en el menú, Tools/Mannage packages
busco pyautogui en el buscador, la encuentra, pulso "Install" y otro error:

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError

Comment: Tienes más de una versión de Python instalada en tu máquina? o estás usando alguna ambiente virtual de python? porque puede ser que no instalaste la librería en la versión de python que estas usando

Comment: Que yo sepa tengo también el python oficial.
c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\
c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\

Comment: Entonces tienes dos versiones, dada la información que das instalaste la librería en la versión oficial, te sugiero que crees un un ambiente virtual con la versión de python que necesitas e instales ahí la libería,  en el [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) se explica con mayor detalle

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ModuleNotFoundError No puedo importar un módulo instalado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/404776/modulenotfounderror-no-puedo-importar-un-m%c3%b3dulo-instalado)